# Mouse Click Sound Delay

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am writing an HTML5 game such that during gameplay, when the mouse button is clicked, a gun shot sound is suppose to play. I do have this functionality working, however, there is a noticeable, small delay from the time the mouse button is clicked to when the sound actually plays.

Here are the existing, relevant snippets of code from my full body script code accounting for this particular functionality:

```
Game = {};

Game.main = (function(sounds) {
    'use strict';

    Mouse = input.Mouse(),

    Shot_sounds = sounds.Shot({
        // none
    }),

    Mouse.registerCommand('mousedown', function(e, elapsedTime) {
        mouseCapture = true;
        if (begin && !end) {
            clicks.current++;
            if (clicks.current >= clicks.limit)
                clicks.current = clicks.limit;
            Shot_sounds.play(clicks.current);
        }
    });

}(Game.sounds));


Game.input = (function() {
    'use strict';

    function Mouse() {
        var that = {
            mouseDown : [],
            mouseUp : [],
            mouseMove : [],
            handlersDown : [],
            handlersUp : [],
            handlersMove : []
        };

        function mouseDown(e) {
            that.mouseDown.push(e);
            //console.log('mousedown - x: ' + e.clientX + ', y: ' + e.clientY);
        }

        function mouseUp(e) {
            that.mouseUp.push(e);
            //console.log('mouseup -   x: ' + e.clientX + ', y: ' + e.clientY);
        }

        function mouseMove(e) {
            that.mouseMove.push(e);
            //console.log('mousemove - x: ' + e.clientX + ', y: ' + e.clientY);
        }

        that.update = function(elapsedTime) {
            var event, handler;
            //
            // Process the mouse events for each of the different kinds of handlers
            for (event = 0; event < that.mouseDown.length; event++) {
                for (handler = 0; handler < that.handlersDown.length; handler++)
                    that.handlersDown[handler](that.mouseDown[event], elapsedTime);
            }
            for (event = 0; event < that.mouseUp.length; event++) {
                for (handler = 0; handler < that.handlersUp.length; handler++)
                    that.handlersUp[handler](that.mouseUp[event], elapsedTime);
            }
            for (event = 0; event < that.mouseMove.length; event++) {
                for (handler = 0; handler < that.handlersMove.length; handler++)
                    that.handlersMove[handler](that.mouseMove[event], elapsedTime);
            }
            //
            // Now that we have processed all the inputs, reset everything back to the empty state
            that.mouseDown.length = 0;
            that.mouseUp.length = 0;
            that.mouseMove.length = 0;
        };

        that.registerCommand = function(type, handler) {
            if (type == 'mousedown')
                that.handlersDown.push(handler);
            else if (type == 'mouseup')
                that.handlersUp.push(handler);
            else if (type == 'mousemove')
                that.handlersMove.push(handler);
        };

        var canvasElement = document.getElementById('canvas-cursor');
        //console.log('offsetX: ' + canvasElement.offsetLeft);
        //console.log('offsetY: ' + canvasElement.offsetTop);
        canvasElement.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown.bind(that));
        canvasElement.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp.bind(that));
        canvasElement.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove.bind(that));

        return that;
    }

    return {
        Mouse : Mouse 
    };
}());

Game.sounds = (function() {
    'use strict';

    var tracks = { 
        shoot_gun: 'media/sounds/shoot_gun.ogg', 
    };

    function Shot(spec) {
        var that = {};
        var clips = [];
        that.load = function(clicks) {
            for (let i = 0; i < clicks; i++) {
                var sound = new Audio();
                sound.src = tracks.shoot_gun;
                clips.push({
                    click: i+1, 
                    audio: sound, 
                    ready: false, 
                    active: false 
                });
            }
            clips.forEach(function(clip) {
                clip.audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
                    clip.ready = true;
                });
                clip.audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
                    that.stop();
                });
            })
        };
        that.play = function(clicks) {
            var clip = clips[clicks-1];
            if (clip.ready) {
                clip.audio.play();
                clip.active = true;
            }
        };
        that.stop = function() {
            clips.forEach(function(clip) {
                if (clip.audio.ended)
                    clip.active = false;
            })
        };
        that.pause = function() {
            clips.forEach(function(clip) {
                if (clip.active)
                    clip.audio.pause();
            })
        };
        that.resume = function() {
            clips.forEach(function(clip) {
                if (clip.active)
                    clip.audio.play();
            })
        };
        return that;
    }

    return {
        Shot : Shot 
    };
}());
```

When searching this problem on my own, I did come across a number of articles describing some kind of known, built-in 300ms delay which does seem to fit the description of the issue I'm having. For solutions to this, the recommendation that I came across was to use a JS module called FastClick:

https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

I followed their instructions for enabling this FastClick module into my code, however, it didn't do anything and made no difference. Specifically, I did the following:

1. Downloaded their fastclick.js file and placed it in my /scripts/ folder with all my other scripts.
2. Inserted the following code into the head tag section of my index.html file:

   ```
   <script type='application/javascript' src='scripts/fastclick.js'></script>
   ```
3. Inserted the following code into the beginning of the body tag section of my index.html file:

   ```
   if ('addEventListener' in document) {
       document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
           FastClick.attach(document.body);
       }, false);
   }
   ```
4. Added a console.log() type comment into code of steps 2 and 3 above to verify that code was being read in and activated.

So after performing the above steps, I didn't see that the native 300ms delay was removed. Also to lend clarity, you'll see the sound file being used is OGG type that unlike MP3, you can remove silence at the beginning of the sound file. So I know the OGG is good and very promptly plays without delay the moment activated.

Then, after carefully reviewing FastClick and their documentation, I did see the following statement:

"FastClick doesn't attach any listeners on desktop browsers."

So I guess that means FastClick won't work in the Chrome desktop browser that I've been using to test my game in. If FastClick can't fix the problem, then at that point I'm at an impasse and I haven't been able to find anything else that documents a fix for this problem.

Comment: You should probably ask a specific question.

Comment: @Difster The question is pretty clear. The OP asked what can be done to remove the 300ms delay between the mouse click and sound firing. The OP mentioned `FastClick` as something that he / she tried but didn't work.

Comment: I don't see a question mark in there anywhere. There is not a clearly defined question.

Comment: @OP: that delay only applies to mobile browsers; the 300ms delay is to make sure the user isn't actually swiping, as opposed to tapping. On a desktop, there's won't be a delay; Fastclick is useless here. (that fastclick only applies to touch devices is stated right at the start of the docs)

Comment: @'I haz kode' Thank you and yes you are correct. The question is how to get rid of the delay.

Comment: @'Chris G' What I am seeing is different. There is most definitely a delay on the desktop browser.

Comment: @jmine83 This might be silly but did you rule out the possibility that your recorded audio file might have a 300ms silent part in the beginning?

Comment: @'I haz kode' Yes that was already confirmed earlier. This was described in my original post with using an OGG file and I also opened the file in Audacity to verify and indeed yes, there is no delay in the audio file itself.